# Insert rvalue in bst

Tags: c++, stl, move, rvalue-reference, allocator

I'm trying to write an STL like container for BST. I have two different functions to insert lvalue and rvalue. Function with rvalue overwrites the all the previous inserted values.

Here is the code:

```
 std::pair<iterator, bool> insert( value_type&& value ) {
    return insert_unique( std::move( value ) );
}

template<typename Vp_> std::pair<iterator, bool> insert_unique( Vp_&& value ) {
    node_holder_ h_             = make_node_holder( std::move( value ) );
    node_pointer_ root_         = ( *header_ ).parent_;
    node_pointer_ inserted_node = h_.release();

    if ( root_ == nullptr ) {
        ( *header_ ).parent_   = inserted_node;
        ( *header_ ).left_     = inserted_node;
        ( *header_ ).right_    = inserted_node;
        inserted_node->parent_ = header_;
        size_++;
        return std::make_pair( make_iterator( inserted_node ), true );
    }

    node_pointer_ parent = root_;
    node_pointer_ x      = root_;

   while ( x != nullptr ) {
        parent = x;
        if ( compare_( inserted_node->key_, x->key_ ) )
            x = x->left_;
        else if ( compare_( x->key_, inserted_node->key_ ) )
            x = x->right_;
        else
            return std::make_pair( make_iterator( x ), false );
    }

    if ( compare_( inserted_node->key_, parent->key_ ) )
        parent->left_ = inserted_node;

    else
        parent->right_ = inserted_node;
    inserted_node->parent_ = parent;
    // Update leftmost and right most
    if ( compare_( inserted_node->key_, leftmost()->key_ ) ) ( *header_ ).left_ = inserted_node;
    if ( !( compare_( inserted_node->key_, rightmost()->key_ ) ) &&
         !( compare_( rightmost()->key_, inserted_node->key_ ) ) ) {
        ( *header_ ).right_   = inserted_node;
        inserted_node->right_ = header_;
    }

    size_++;
    return std::make_pair( make_iterator( inserted_node ), true );
}

node_holder_ make_node_holder( value_type&& value ) {
    // std::cout << "args holders " << std::endl;
    node_allocator_& na_ = get_allocator();
    node_holder_ nh_( na_.allocate( 1 ), node_destructor_( na_ ) );
    node_traits_::construct( na_, nh_.get(), std::move( value ) );
    nh_.get_deleter().value_constructed_ = true;
    return std::move( nh_ );
}
```

I referred to the [talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11) by Scott-Meyers and cascaded the rvalue by using std::move.  But, there is some error in the code which is causing the overwrite. Can you please share if you are able to identify the error causing this issue?

[Code repository](https://github.com/TusharChugh/cplusplus-bst). The bst.h class is in lib/ directory.

Please share if you have any other comments and feedback on the code.

Comment: why all the static_casts?

Comment: Was using it to handle nullptr case before. Forgot to update it. Thanks for pointing it out.  I think the issue is with node allocation.

Comment: There isn't a question mark anywhere.

Comment: @JGroven. Sorry, I'm a new user. Added the question.